# Max filesize not taking effect from php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I know this is a massive repost but I couldn't figure this out. The server is Ubuntu using nginx.

Doing `phpinfo()` I see the configuration file I am using is `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`.

These are the properties I set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
```

I restarted nginx, as well as the `php7.0-fpm` process and the max upload size is still not changing.

I am using wordpress so as a last resort I even tried using a plugin that increases the max upload size and even that didn't work.

I also tried setting it in my .htaccess as well and still nothing:

```
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value uploads_max_filesize 256M
```

Comment: Did you restart the apache service?

Comment: @RudyM I am using nginx, I restarted nginx yes.

Comment: This was a bing search result, surprisingly not SO. So check here: https://serverfault.com/a/450365

Comment: it is possible that there is an additional .ini file that is loaded after your php.ini, to check this, can you check or share the contents of your `phpinfo()`? if you think this that is not the case, it can also possible that `post_max_size ` or `uploads_max_filesize` is being set/change on runtime via a php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default NGINX has a limit of 1MB on file uploads. To change this you will need to set the  client_max_body_size variable. You can do this  in the http block in your nginx.conf

```
http {
    #...
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        client_body_timeout 120s; # Default is 60, May need to be increased for very large uploads
    #...
}
```

If you are expecting upload very large files where upload times will exceed 60 seconds you will also need to add the  `client_body_timeout` variable with a large value

After updating you NGINX configuration don’t forget to restart NGINX.

you need to restart nginx and php to reload the configs. This can be done using the following commands;

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Note:if you don't have to host multiple
Websites just add it to the server block

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 8M;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it, turns out it was nginx's problem and not php.

Comment: Glad it helped... :D

Answer (score 2):

The answer I found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/450365):

> Have you tried to put your php.ini under /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini? This is normally the default location that php reads from, if I understand php5-fpm correctly.

Comment: I do not have a php5 folder, and I am running php 7.1.

Comment: How about the answer that @JeanPaulRuiz gave?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

When you mention that your server uses nginx it is unnecesary to use an .htaccess file since those are for Apache servers.

That being said, I would try a couple of things.

Do you know what's the ini file of your php instance?

You mention the one for php 7 but you could also have php 5 installed.

If you go to your console and type "php --ini" what's the loaded configuration file?

Once you know that, using vi / vim or your editor of choice you can set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Now, have into account that you have to restart your services, both php and nginx:

for php 5:

```
service php5-fpm reload
```

for php 7:

```
service php7-fpm reload
```

for nginx:

```
service nginx reload
```

try printing the current values as well:

```
$uploadMaxFilesize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
$postMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Also, since this is for WordPress, did you try setting it up in the WordPress admin settings?

Admin Dashboard > Settings > Upload Settings

Comment: Just did everything you said. I have php 5.6, 7.0, and 7.1 installed. I just made the same changes to every php.ini file in all those folders, and restarted all running php processes and nginx. Still not working. BUT the output from those two php functions at the end of your post did both output `256M` so that is strange.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mine got solved by using `sudo service php-fpm reload`

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things I had to change to get it working for me.

Firstly from user NID [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334172/12578639), add this to your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file (inside the http block):

```
http {
    #...
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        client_body_timeout 120s; # Default is 60, May need to be increased for very large uploads
    #...
}
```

Then I also had to follow something similar to user Just Rudy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334036/12578639).

Edit your `php.ini` file - contrary to many guides, for me it was not located in my wordpress root folder, but instead, `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`.

There should be some predefined values for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Change these to what you want.

Restart nginx and php-fpm:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```